# is there a way to check if a column has correct format of date in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a date column in my table. I want to retrieve all the dates that are non valid (ex, 12/11 or 12/2002). the data type of column is not DATE. How can I approach it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Another good example why it's such a horrible idea to store date values in `varchar` or `text` columns. Do you have a chance to fix the broken data model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the desired format of the data, you can use a regular expression:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE NOT col ~ '^\d{1,4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$';
```

This would be for dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: if I want to check timestamp along with date, should I do pattern match for that along with date pattern matching?

Comment: You mean if you have a timestamp? Sure, but that would be a different pattern.

Comment: I am trying to check if dates are correct according to the days in month. I tried following regular expression to check that, however it shows the correct values wrong. Could someone point out where am I doing the mistakes? ``` '^((19|20)[0-9](0-9)-(0[13578]|1[02])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|
   ((19|20)(0-9)(0-9)-(0[469]|11)-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))| 
   ((19|20)(0-9)(0-9)-02-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|
   (((19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|2000)-02-29)$' ``` these are some wrong dates as per code: 
2006-03-06 
2016-06-14 
2014-09-24 
2019-10-18